# How do I prevent homemade app buttons from being invisible on old Android phones / Moto 3G?

Tags: android, android-studio, invisible, motorola, motorola-droid

I have developed an app using Android Studio that generally works on most Android phones. However, on old Android phones (and most recently on Moto 3G, running Android 6.0), the "Start" button on the homescreen, which I've created in Android Studio, is invisible. The button is a *.png image that can be activated when tapped to start the application. Although invisible, the button can still be tapped and activated. So why isn't it showing up? Again, this error only occurs in ~2% of phones.

(1)  I tried to force the button to be visible (see below), but that didn't didn't solve the problem.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/startbutton"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/speciesListButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

(2)  The button is large (2083 x 333 px, 21 kb) but scalable obviously. Could this be the issue with making it visible on old phones?

(3)  I wonder if the problem is more related to **small** phones, more so than old phones. However, I'm able to run this app just fine as an emulator of comparable screen size. So this doesn't add up either.

(4)  Does Moto 3G have some inherent problems / limitations?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Could you include a [mre]?  As-is, this wouldn't be enough to reproduce it even _with_ that phone in hand.  Also, for debugging if it's a size thing, take a look at the Android Studio layout inspector.  It may also be a combination of size and Android version.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can find other aspects of code to include here to make it reproducible.  I wish there were a Moto 3G emulator. I can't re-create this problem on my computer with screens of any size. So I have to suspect that it is something with particular phones. Is there a place to find work-arounds for specific phones?

Comment: For better or worse, you're in the right place: Stack Overflow's probably your best bet for workarounds.